# Windows 7 BSOD at same occasions

Tags: windows-7, bsod, dial-up

Since I installed Win7 on my DELL Inspiron 1520 notebook, I frequently experience BSODs.

I noticed that those nearly only happen on two occasions

- disconnecting a DUN connection (Bluetooth, UMTS USB stick, even VPN)
- with certain file open dialogs (most of the time UPLOADING in Firefox or Chrome, strangely enough downloading with dialog works perfect)

The BSOD doesn't appear always on these actions.

BluescreenView told me that most of the time it is

- srv2.sys+45883 or
- srv2.sys+42982 or
- ntoskrnl.exe+71ef2
- ntoskrnl.exe+71f00
- ntoskrnl.exe+ef6a2

Now I read that srv2.sys is for NETBIOS sharing, which could be triggered when opening the file open dialog. All unused NICs are deactivated.

Any ideas how to fix this?

EDIT: The same BSODs occur after installing some drivers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this thread: [srv2.sys causing BSOD in Windows 7 Ultimate x64](http://www.techsupportforum.com/microsoft-support/windows-vista-windows-7-support/469596-srv2-sys-causing-bsod-windows-7-ultimate-x64.html).

There the problem was analyzed as caused by the personal firewall, which blocks local NETBIOS ports, thus causing Windows 7 system services to crash because of denial of access to the ports, and specially the Smb 2.0 Server driver srv2.sys.

I would turn all firewalls off for a time, including that of Windows. (If you're behind a router, you don't really need a firewall in any case.) If the problem disappears, then replace your firewall by another.

The above thread also recommends updating the Asus AI Suite ATK0110 utility drive. If that applies to your case, the Asus driver updates link is [here](http://support.asus.com/download/download.aspx).

**EDIT**

According to your input, this is probably a driver problem.
In any case, a driver is always the most likely cause of a BSOD.

Your case is similar to that discussed in this [thread](http://en.community.dell.com/forums/t/19274527.aspx), that discusses drivers for Win7 for the Inspiron 1520. It offers the following links:

Intel graphics drivers: [Intel Download Center](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx)
nVidia graphics drivers: [nVidia Drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us)
Media Card Reader drivers: from Dell (listed for another laptop) in [Dell Search for R234107](http://support.us.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R234107&formatcnt=1&libid=0&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&fileid=336870)
Dell Wireless 355 Bluetooth adapter: [here](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dsn/en/document?docid=2D785CBB1BBFF5F1E040A68F5B282502)

Comment: I guess the ASUS drive doesn't apply here, but +1 for the NETBIOS combined with firewall hint. Will accept if it works!

Comment: Sorry, disabled the firewall and got another srv2.sys+42982 combined with ntoskrnl.exe+71ef2 when the open file dialog opened in my browser.

Comment: @Tarnschaf: Have you checked for viruses? This problem is not normal.

Comment: I use the MSE virus scanner and checked with BitDefender: Both didn't find anything suspicious!

Comment: Might need to check your system using "sfc /scannow". See this article: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html, as well as this one: http://www.updatexp.com/scannow-sfc.html

Comment: sfc /scannow found no problems also

Comment: @Tarnschaf: See my edit.

Comment: @harrymc: thanks for the link to the drivers. Some are new to me and I installed them. Will drop a note here if/how they influence my BSODs.

Comment: Hi, the BSOD still appears when trying to upload a file in the browser.

Comment: The problem was not related to a firewall, but probably a driver incompatibility (model has no Win7 logo). In the meantime I bought a new laptop with Win7 and re-installed Windows XP on the Inspiron 1520.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating every driver you can download from Dell. Sounds like some sort of hardware glitch (wildly guessing without knowing the STOP number).

Comment: I'm afraid DELL does not provide win7 drivers because my notebook model is not officially supported with win7. I can't use the vista drivers because they are x86, my win7 is x64.

Comment: I know it's not the answer you're looking for, but sometimes there's really good reason a particular OS is not supported on hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Aaaancient question, but I ran across the same issue on Windows 8.1 recently:

> with certain file open dialogs (most of the time UPLOADING in Firefox or Chrome, strangely enough downloading with dialog works perfect)

It was really persistent, almost 75 % of the time it happened in an identical fashion:

1. In Firefox, open some website that has an "Open File" dialog button on it
2. Click the button
3. In the dialog address bar, paste **an URL** to some file on a website.

   - I used image files, like https://example.com/example.gif or https://example.com/example.jpg
4. Press the "Open" button
5. BSOD would happen 75 % of the time, all of a sudden

Now, in my case, the fix was simple, but I found it by sheer accident:

**Clear your Temporary Internet Files**
For example using the built-in Disk Cleanup program (Windows key --> disk cleanup).

That's it. I never got another BSOD.

I think somehow the "temp" dirs (it has some sort of rotation with different "hex" directories) becomes overpopulated, even if you still have hundreds of gigabytes of disk space left on C:

Answer (score 0):

Have installed your firmware? Your laptop model comes with Vista drivers and those work perfectly with Windows 7. I have Windows 7 installed on the same model and  it works perfectly with the Vista drivers that came with the laptop. If you don't have your drivers CD/DVD download them from [this link](http://supportapj.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?c=in&l=en&s=gen&ServiceTag=&SystemID=INS_PNT_PM_1520&os=WLH&osl=en&catid=&impid=)

Comment: Well, I run the 64 bit version of Windows, I bet you decided for the x86 one? I don't think I should or can install those drivers.